# Validate Uri using a ConfigurationValidator or other validator

Tags: .net, validation, uri

In a custom configuration section of a config file I want to have properties or elements define a new scheme, host and port for a service endpoint, but not define the path.
So these should be allowed `https://newhost/` or `http://newhost:800`, but not `newhost:800`, `http://newhost/path/to/service`.

What would be the best option to implement?

It feels like there should be a good overload of a Uri.Parse, UriParser that would make it easy. Is there a UriValidator that I have missed? Or is regex going to be the best option (so that it can easily disallow the path)?

Note that this isn't specific to a ConfigurationValidator as a general validator that can be reused would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always the `GetLeftPart` method of the `Uri` class that could help here.

[GetLeftPart Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx)

The GetLeftPart method takes an enumeration from the [UriPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x82988a2.aspx) system enumeration, one of which (`UriPartial.Authority`) will return:

> The scheme and authority segments of
>   the URI.

This effectively removes any extraneous path information that may be in the original string, and will usually return a zero-length string if the Uri supplied does not contain a valid [scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx) (i.e. the http or https etc. parts of the Uri) and/or authority (i.e. in your example, this is the `newhost` part of the Uri).

From here, you should be able to compare the return value of the call to `GetLLeftPart` with the original Uri string, and if they're different, the Uri is "invalid".  If they're the same, the Uri is "valid" (for your purposes).

Here's a simple example class that will perform this "validation" returning either True or False for the Uri (both C# and VB.NET versions):

**C#**

```
public static class UriValidator
{
    public static bool IsUriValid(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            string original_uri = uri;
            if (uri.Substring(uri.Length - 1, 1) == "/")
            {
                original_uri = uri.Substring(0, uri.Length - 1);
            }
            Uri myUri = new Uri(original_uri);
            string new_uri = myUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            if (original_uri.ToLower() == new_uri.ToLower())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }            
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Public Class UriValidator
    Public Shared Function IsUriValid(ByVal uri As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim original_uri = uri
            If uri.Substring(uri.Length - 1, 1) = "/" Then
                original_uri = uri.Substring(0, uri.Length - 1)
            End If
            Dim myUri As Uri = New Uri(original_uri)
            Dim new_uri As String = myUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
            If original_uri.ToLower = new_uri.ToLower Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

I ran a simple test using this class:

```
Console.WriteLine("https://newhost/" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("https://newhost/"));
Console.WriteLine("http://newhost:800" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("http://newhost:800"));
Console.WriteLine("newhost:800" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("newhost:800"));
Console.WriteLine("newhost:" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("newhost:"));
Console.WriteLine("qwerty:newhost" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("qwerty:newhost"));
Console.WriteLine("qwerty://newhost" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("qwerty://newhost"));
Console.WriteLine("qwerty://newhost:800" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("qwerty://newhost:800"));
Console.WriteLine("http://newhost/path/to/service" + "  " + UriValidator.IsUriValid("http://newhost/path/to/service"));
```

And it gave the following output:

> https://newhost/  True
>   http://newhost:800  True
>   newhost:800 False
>   newhost:  False
>   qwerty:newhost False
>   qwerty://newhost  True
>   qwerty://newhost:800  True
>   http://newhost/path/to/service  False

which seems to be what you're after!

Note that Uri's like `qwerty://newhost` still validate as `True` as qwerty *could* be a valid protocol registered on your system.  If you only wanted to allow `http` and/or `https`, it should be trivial to add this in.